# Blazor Blazored.SessionStorage http error 500 as soon as inject in index.razor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor **server-side app** and am trying `Blazor.SessionStorage` for session storage but as soon as I add `@inject Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService sessionStorage` to `index.razor` I get a `HTTP error 500 failed to load resource`.

I have added `services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();` to `startup.cs`.

Comment: check render-mode in _Host what s that value ?
server or something else ?
for example :
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />

Comment: ServerPrerendered

Comment: change it to server and test

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did that and just reinserted @inject Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService sessionStorage in index.razor but  it did not resolve the issue.